# Load variables from library into controller files?

Tags: php, codeigniter

On my site, i use an API to get the users IP address and then show details based on the IP, such as city, location e.t.c

I had the same code running on each view that got the ipaddress, and then ran it through the API returning JSON info.

I realised, this wasn't a good idea having it being loaded on every page, and having to edit each file if i ever need to change my API key e.t.c

So i created a library file called 'globals'

and then added it into autoload.php

my current library looks like this

```
 foreach (array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 
 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 
 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED', 'REMOTE_ADDR') as $key){
    if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true){
        foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]) as $ip){
            $ip = trim($ip); // just to be safe

            if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, 
 FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) !== false){
               $userip = $ip;
            }
        }
    }
}

 $details = 
 json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.ipdata.co/{$userip}?api-key=XXXXXXXXXXX));


// Create customized config variables
$config['timezone']= $details->time_zone->name;
$config['regioncode']= $details->country_code . "-" .$details->region_code;
$config['city']= $details->city;
```

in my view files i can simply put

echo $regioncode;

and it will show the regioncode, based from the library file,

However if i put $regioncode in a controller file, it's saying undefined variable.

Any ideas on how i can load these in controllers?

Comment: so you bascially want to get information about an ip address - and you dont want to call this all the time ?

Comment: Yeah, because i am limited to 1500 requests per day, so makes sense to just call it when it's needed

Comment: alright - is it possible to store that data in a db - do you have mysql or something like that? if so - i think you should update those informations every month or week (because this data are usually pretty static - except maybe the language part - but i think you can neglect it)

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar. All you have to do is store the data you want in a session variable (what I do), or a cookie. A cookie might be a better option if you really want to reduce your api calls, but might not be a good option if your site revolves around geolocation (like finding what is nearby to a user).

In any case, all you'd have to do is check if it (the cookie or session variable) is set before calling the api, if it is, then you just fetch it.

Introducing globals like you are doing won't persist across page reloads/redirects .etc. So it would really only reduce concurrent calls for that single instance.

Comment: Yeah, a lot of my site is based on geolocation, how ever it just gets the country and uses results from my DB with the same country in a field. If i were to store session data, does it automatically get re-set when the user goes back on the website? this is all kind of new to me, so not really sure how it works!

Comment: Let's say the user leaves your site and goes to google or fb, whatever, for an hour. When they come back to your site, their session should still be set, therefore the data should still be available. It ultimately depends on how long your session last until it expires (which is configurable in ci). If you want longer term e.g. a day or more, I'd suggest storing a cookie on the users system.